# Android camera2 flash not fired in low light conditions in auto flash mode

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I used camera2 to capture picture, and set the flash mode to auto. I set the request parameters as following.

```
CaptureRequest.Builder stillCaptureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
stillCaptureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
```

In the code above, the flash should be fired in low-light conditions. But it didn't work as expected. The flash **didn't** get fired in low-light conditions.

How can I set camera2 to auto flash mode?

Comment: hey you found the solution? i facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I can help you!

Try to set Flash_mode to OFF if you are using AE_MODE:

```
 builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
 builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
```

and later update your preview setting again a repeatingRequest to your builder and callback:

```
mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(builder.build(),
                    callback, backgroundHandler);
```

Also remember that if you want to check if everything is set correctly you can recover the state of your flash using `result.get(CaptureResult.FLASH_STATE)` from your captureCalback return value after or before take a picture.

In other way, don't forget to don't update the preview when the flash is being shoot or you will put off your flash before the photo as been shoot.

Comment: This does not solve the issue.. Any other way out? i have same problem with auto flash.

Answer (score 0):

try this for auto flash

```
 // Use the same AE and AF modes as the preview.
            captureStillBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            captureStillBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
```